# TypeError: Cannot read property 'code' of null

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am registering my user, in the mongo DB. I am creating an instance of the data in the form and calling .save() method of mongoose. However, my app crashes (Although users are getting saved in the database perfectly):-

Initially, I thought that I am not saving "confirm password" in the instance so that may be creating an error but even after commenting that part of the code problem still persists.

I have not created anything by the name of **code** in my files.

**Following is my error**

```
Error:-
events.js:298
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event

TypeError: Cannot read property 'code' of null
```

**This is my post request:-**

```
router.post("/signup", function(req,res){
let registered_user=new User(req.body);
registered_user.save(function(err, doc){
    if(err){
        console.log("Something went Wrong");
    }
    if(err.code===11000){
        console.log("User with same details already registed");
    }
});
res.redirect("/");
});
```

**This is my HTML Form:-**

```
<form action="/signup" method="POST">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label><strong>Enrollment Number</strong>
            <br> 
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="EnrollNumber" placeholder="Enrollment Number" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label><strong>Email:-</strong>
            <br> 
        <input class="form-control" type="email" name="Email" placeholder="Email" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label><strong>Name</strong>
            <br>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="Name" placeholder="Name" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label><strong>Department</strong> 
        <select id="" name="Department" required>
            (...)
          </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label><strong>Position</strong> 
        <select id="" name="Role" required>
            <option value="Student">Student </option>
            ...(Some more)
          </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label><strong>Gender</strong> 
        <select id="" name="Gender" required>
            (...)
          </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label><strong>password :</strong><br>
        <input name="password" id="password" type="password" onkeyup='check();'>
      </label>
      <br>
      <label><strong>Confirm Password:</strong>
        <br> 
        <input type="password" id="confirm_password" onkeyup='check();'> 
        <span id='message'></span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-info btn-block">Submit!</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

**And My User Schema**

```
var UserSchema=new mongoose.Schema({
Name: {
    type:String,
    required: true
},
Email: {
    type:String,
    required: true,
    unique: true
},
Role: {
    type:String,
    required: true
},
EnrollNumber: {
    type:Number,
    required: true,
    unique: true
},
password: {
    type:String,
    required: true
},
Department: {
    type:String,
    required: true
},
Gender: {
    type:String,
    required: true
}
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're using 2 `if` statements.

The first `if (err) {}` will be evaluated and then there is the other `if (err.code) {}` which too will be evaluated causing the `TypeError` to be thrown.

It looks like what you're trying to do is this

```
if (err) {
    if (err.code === 11000) {
        console.log('User was already registered');
    }
}
return 'User saved!';
```

Comment: It does, but you'll run into the same problems there. You're most likely looking to return in the first `if` or have a nested `if` instead.